# Remove extraneous Symbols/Characters in a variable

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a variable `$student` whose value is from the database. When I tried displaying it in a table using Ajax callback function, it throws an error saying:

[image]

But when I initialized the variable `$student` with a constant string, the code turns out good. For example:

```
$student = 'Constant String';
```

I guess my problem is that `$student` fetch from the database contains symbols/characters, that causes Ajax to break out. Below is the sample characters:

```
"\0" - NULL
"\t" - tab
"\n" - new line
"\x0B" - vertical tab
"\r" - carriage return
```

How will I get rid of these characters in my variable?

Comment: A possible starting point might be having a look at the sanitization functions provided by Drupal: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/sanitization/7 Hope it helps,

Comment: How are those characters getting into the variable? I assume that `variable_set` and `variable_get` are being used?